# evaluating item.item.name in flatlist

Tags: arrays, react-native, object, react-native-flatlist

I have a FaltList component that looks like this:

```
<FlatList>
data = {this.state.array}
...
renderItem={({ item }) => (
 <View>
  <Text>hello, {item.item.name}</Text>
 </View>
)}
...
</FlatList>
```

this.state.array looks like this:

```
Array [
  Object {
    "//user1": Object {
      "id": "//user1",
      "name": "Peter",
    },
    "//user2": Object {
      "id": "//user2",
      "name": "Tim",
    },
  },
]
```

I get an error which says:

> TypeError: undefined is not an object (evaluating 'item.item.name')

do you know how to fix it? Thank you!!

Comment: You want to map over the users in each object of the array ?

Comment: @HichamELBSI yes.